# Resources to learn OOP Design Patterns in regards to data driven applications

Tags: c#

Hi I'm trying to find some good resources for using OOP in the context of Data driven applications.  I have a relativity firm grasp of OOP I use objects, interfaces, and delegates quite often in my code.  However, I find more often then not in when I write data driven apps ( which is the bulk of my work right now ) I tend to veer to a functional approach.  This is mostly because I don't know the right way to do it I guess.

I've only been programming for about a year and recently I've been putting allot of time into trying to improve my knowledge of design patterns (I'm currently reading C# 3.0 Design Patterns watching the john skeet videos) and really writing unit test for everything.  However, I find that allot of examples that I see tend to not deal with data driven apps.  More with like Truck inheritances from car stuff lol

So I was wondering if anyone could point me in the directions of some good videos, tutorials or even books on the subject ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Martin Fowlers Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture goes over quite a few "Data Driven" Patterns http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/.

Check out:

Table Data Gateway: http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/tableDataGateway.html

Row Data Gateway: http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/rowDataGateway.html

Table Module: http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/tableModule.html

In fact the whole book is worth a look :-)